# What would be a possible reason for a organism or plant being red-colored

Tags: science-based

The title says it all but I was wondering if there could be some sort of hypothetical plant that could harvest solar light via the red pigment.

Comment: this has been asked many times and the answer is always the same, the color of plants is basically arbitrary luck.

Comment: stripping away the chlorophyl, most otherwise green plants would appear red. chlorophyl is not the only substance used for photosynthesis. so technically, almost _all_ plants harvest light via red pigment; just to a lesser degree.

Answer (score 2):

## These exist in real life

This happens mostly in tropical plants. In many of these plants it is theorized that the red coloration is used to produce toxins, and signal potential consumers to stay away. Additionally it may provide a kind of sunscreen for the chlorophyll in plants where there is too much sun. green is the most efficient color for photosynthesis, but if there's always an excess of light, efficiency may not be important, so the red coloring provides a kind of shade. This is an area of some research, but I think the fact that they exist in real life answers the question.